# Random Numbers with assigned Probability in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Following is what I am trying to do:

I have got a bunch of items, lets say from A to J, a total of 10 items. Now I want to generate a total of 20 draws and in each draw I need 3 items from the above 10 items. Now if the first item comes out as A, it should not show up in second and third item irrespective of its assigned probability.

Lets say:

A - 4%
B - 20%
C - 1%
D - 16%
E - 5%
F - 7%
G - 3%
H - 21%
I - 6%
J - 17%

Now, I need to randomly generate 3 items from the above list in each draw, according to their assigned probabilities, but lets say if first item is B, the second and third item should not be B. I should repeat the same process for 20 draws.

Answer Should Look something like this:

```
         1st Item    2nd Item   3rd Item
1st Draw   B            D           J
2nd Draw   D            E           F
3rd Draw   B            H           G
```

The numbers should be generated according to their assigned probabilities.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to just be a homework dump rather than asking a specific question.

Comment: As a starter idea, you could use RAND()*Prob(index)  to generate 10 numbers and pick the lowest 3 in each draw. Not completely sure that works statistically but it should be close.

Comment: What happens in the other 2% of cases?

Comment: Hi YowE3k, I have corrected the question. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: how do the probabilities redistribute after once an option has been removed from the set? (ie second pick) How do they rebalnce when two options have been removed? (third pick)

Comment: Wow it has not been said yet after 4 hours...what have your tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a formula route:

You will need to build two helper columns.  The first is a running total

I put your values in G1:H10

Then in I1 I put `1`

In I2 I put:

```
=I1+(H1*100)
```

And copied down:

[image]

I then created the second helper.  In K1 I put:

```
=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(ROW(1:1),I:I))
```

And copied down 100 rows.

[image]

This created a dynamic range of the probability.

Then in B2 I put:

```
=INDEX($K:$K,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$100)/(COUNTIF($A2:A2,$K$1:$K$100)=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,100-SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($A2:A2,$K$1:$K$100)))))
```

Copied over three and down as many as wanted:

[image]

Caveats:

- This works only with whole percentages, no `20.513%`.
- Every choice in the table must be at least `1%`.
- The total percentage must equal `100%`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way according to this website (https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/372071-random-numbers-assigned-probabilities.html) post #7.  You can use cumulative value and do the similar test.

Add a `helper column C` and use this formula: `=SUM($B$2:B2)`, and drag down.

On `cell F2`, you can enter this formula:

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,COUNTIF($C$2:$C$11,"<="&RAND())+1)`

It is basically counting the rows using `RAND` function and add 1 (the header row) to pick the item.  Give it a try and let me know.

[image]

Comment: Except that this does not guarantee unique per draw.

Comment: @ScottCraner, good catch.  Thank you.  Forgot that criteria.  I will need to rethink about this during the weekend.

Comment: ian0411, good find. The use of cumulative distribution functions, or more strictly, inverse cumulative distribution functions (cdf's), is a foundation of Monte Carlo simulation. I've taken ideas from both your solution and @ScottCraner's to develop a third solution.

Comment: @DMM, too bad that I still can't find a good way to make the unique selection.  Also tried to include `REPT` function to expand the array but couldn't make it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that combines the approaches in the two earlier answers. Like ian0411's answer it utilises the cumulative probability distribution. It also utilises Scott Craner's techique of constructing an array of 0's and 1's which indicate matches between the possible outcomes (A,...,J) and those which have already been drawn.

The formula in cell`P2` is

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,1+IFERROR(MATCH(RAND(),MMULT($D$2:$M$11,($B$2:$B$11)*(1-COUNTIF($O2:O2,$A$2:$A$11))/SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$11,(1-COUNTIF($O2:O2,$A$2:$A$11))))),0))
```

and this is copied into cells `Q2` and `R2` and then dragged down for each draw.

[image]

The probability distribution in `$B$2:$B$11` has elements replaced by zeroes for any prior drawn items in the current draw (hat-tip to Scott for how this was achieved). The adjusted distribution is converted to a cumulative format via the kludgy matrix multiplication operation (couldn't think of a more elegant approach) and normalised to a "proper" cumulative distribution by dividing by the sum of its elements. Rather than using `=1+COUNTIF(cumdist,"<="&RAND())` (where `cumdist` is the cumulative distribution) to pick out the element of `cumdist` matching to the random variable, I have used an alternative of `=1+IFERROR(MATCH(RAND(),cumdist),0)`.